# Pointers to Pointers: What datatype with variable length strings?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types

I need to store a list of names in C. I decided a good way to do this would be to use double pointers (or pointers-to-pointers).

So I will have an array of names. Each array value is a pointer to another array: the name, stored as a character array.

The names might look like

```
unsigned char *name = "Joseph";
```

etc.

And then I would have a list of names (double pointer), to which I could (dynamically) assign each name (single pointer).

```
(type) **listOfNames;
```

My question is: what *type* should the double pointer be? Since it is a pointer to a pointer, I was thinking that it must be large enough to hold an arbitrary memory address: `unsigned long`, maybe? Or is there another type meant specifically for double pointers?

Alternatively — is there a better way of storing a variable-length array or variable-length strings?

Comment: Just `char`, or `unsigned char` if you really need that. The size of a pointer to T is not the same as the size of a T.

Comment: Oh, so just `char **list;`?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you would have trouble making it point to string literals.

Comment: @user3121023 You don't have to, e.g. `char const *listOfNames[20];`

Comment: Issue is that the names are not `const`. I am reading them from a file. Thus a variable length array of variable length strings. I don't know how long anything will be at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a collection of `unsigned char *` values:

```
unsigned char *name_0 = "Joseph";
unsigned char *name_1 = "Helen";
unsigned char *name_2 = "Maximillian";
```

Then you can create:

```
unsigned char *data[] = { name_0, name_1, name_2 };
unsigned char **listOfNames = data;
```

Note that you need to allocate space for the list of pointers — in my code, that's the `data` array. You could use `malloc()` instead, but you'd need to remember to code the matching `free()` at some point.

Adding appropriate `const` qualifications is left as an exercise in frustration to the interested reader.

If you are reading a variable length list of names from a file a run time, with (presumably) one name per line, then you'd do best with POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

There must be a number of other questions that deal with this scenario, so I'll be terse with this code:

```
char **read_file(FILE *fp)
{
    char  *buffer = 0;
    size_t bufsiz = 0;
    char **lines = 0;
    size_t n_lines = 0;
    size_t n_alloc = 0;

    while (getline(&buffer, &bufsiz, fp) > 0)
    {
        if (n_lines + 1 >= n_alloc)
        {
            size_t new_num = (n_alloc + 1) * 2;
            size_t new_size = new_num * sizeof(*lines);
            char **new_lines = realloc(lines, new_size);
            if (new_lines == 0)
            {
                free(buffer);
                free(lines);
                return(0);
            }
            lines = new_lines;
            n_alloc = new_num;
        }
        lines[n_lines++] = strdup(buffer);  // Includes newline!
    }
    lines[n_lines] = 0;  // Null terminate list of strings
    free(buffer);        // Release input line's memory
    return lines;
}
```

Note that the code uses plain `char` and not `unsigned char`.  You face some issues if you use `unsigned char` because neither `getline()` nor `strdup()` expects to work with `unsigned char`.  While you can cast your way around the issue, it is messy to do so.

Comment: I ended up using a slightly less-glorified version of that code. Some minor differences, including the fact that my list is CSV. I also didn't use `strdup()` but instead re-declared the buffer variable at the start of each loop.

Comment: Oh, yes — drat!  I forgot to release `buffer` before returning, so my code leaks (well, leaked) memory.  Using variations on the theme is fine — encouraged, even.

Comment: How about `-1` as the return test for `getline`?

Comment: Yes, I needed to reread the manual page.  I'd probably go with `> 0` as the condition, but it will never return 0 anyway — either -1 or some number larger than zero.